# setting tracepoint in future file being sourced in R

Tags: r, debugging

I have a file, `test.R` :

```
somefunc<-function(){
    print("Hello")
    print("World")
}
somefunc()
print("The End")
```

I want to set a tracepoint on the first line of `somefunc`.  So I try,

```
> trace(what='somefunc', tracer=browser, at=1)
Error in getFunction(what, where = whereF) : no function ‘somefunc’ found
No traceback available
```

Ok, so it is not in the namespace.  Let's load the file (so the function is in our current namespace) and then set the tracepoint...

```
> source("test.R")
[1] "Hello"
[1] "World"
[1] "The End"
> trace(what='somefunc', tracer=browser, at=1)
[1] "somefunc"
```

Now run the file again.

```
> source("test.R")
[1] "Hello"
[1] "World"
[1] "The End"
```

Alas, the breakpoint isn't hit.  Presumably, the act of loading the file again clobbered the previous function (and tracepoint) in namespace.

I can only hit the tracepoint, after I've loaded the file and called the function directly through the interpreter.  E.g.

```
> source("test.R")
[1] "Hello"
[1] "World"
[1] "The End"
> trace(what='somefunc', tracer=browser, at=1)
[1] "somefunc"
> somefunc()
Tracing somefunc() step 1 
Called from: eval(expr, p)
Browse[1]>
```

QUESTIONS :

1. How do I set a breakpoint on a function that is to be loaded / sourced in R?
2. How do I previously set tracepoints when reloading the sourced file?

NOTE :

I'm not looking for the 'I like RStudio, why don't you try using that?' answer.